# grails: afterInterceptor / beforeInterceptor for Service?

Tags: grails, interceptor

We have a Grails 2.5 app, which has a Quartz job, which calls a service method (to close expired sessions).

We have a base and USA version of the app. The USA version needs to do some additional stuff, which we would usually do in a USA specific exploded plugin, to separate the logic.

However, we cant think of a way to "hook" into the call.  In java, we would define an interface, and some kind of factory to pull out the right method. Or something like filter chaining.  What is the grails way of doing something like this?

We could obviously hard code the additional USA logic in the base system,e.g.

```
Session closeSession(Sesssion session) {
        session.endedAt = new Date()
        session.save()

        // USA stuff hacked in here:
        if (SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VAR == "usa") {
            // call some complicated function in its own transaction so 
            // if it fails it doesnt affect closing the session
            com.something.something.complicatedFunction(session)
        }
        // end USA hack

        return session.
}
```

however, this has the massive drawback that our base system has to now include the USA plugin - it has created a compile time dependency between the two.

What would be ideal is something like the afterInterceptor, but for a service class.

We could use the observer pattern, and register the observer in the bootstrap of the exploded plugin.  This would allow us to compile without the USA code for the non USA systems.  The interceptor is so much more elegant though.

Comment: If you want to add code, how could you also not be adding a compile time dependency, whether that be a plugin or other included code?

Comment: @James If we used just used the if statement, it would mean that our base builds for Europe would need to have the exploded plugins for the USA as part of their compile time dependencies.  We dont want that.

Comment: You could have 2 plugins. One for normal and one for USA. Each of the plugins could implement a bean of the same name. The base application could include either plugin as a dependency depending on which of the implementations you want.